# Working with pointers: program that sorts an integer array, segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, loops, sorting, pointers

I am trying to make a program with the following properties: Program with the prototype int*max_sorted(int array[], int laenge, int max), which orders the integers in the array. Create an integer array of the size max+1 on the heap and fill all positions with zero. Then the array which is given to the function is read. If a integer x is read, the value of the array on the heap at position x is incremented by one. Then array is overriden: if the value n at postion i of the array on the heap is read, i is written n times in the array (current position).  The code below gives segmentation fault:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int *max_sorted(int array[],int laenge, int max){
  int k,l;
  int *ptr;

  ptr= malloc((max+1)*sizeof(int)); /*allocates memory for new array*/
  if(ptr==NULL || max<0){
    return NULL;   /*error*/
  }
  for(k=0; k<max+1; k++){      /*sets all values of ptr array to 0*/
    ptr[k]=0; 
  }


  for(k=0;k<laenge;k++){               
    ptr[array[k]]++;      
   }



  for(k=0;k<max+1;k++){
    if(ptr[k]!=0){
    array[k-l]=k*ptr[k]; 
    }
    else{
      l++;
    }
  }




  free(ptr);
  return array;
}





int main(void){


  int array[3]={2,1,3};
  int laenge=3;
  int max=3;
  int k;
  int*ptr;
  ptr=max_sorted(array,laenge,max);
   for(k=0;k<laenge;k++){
    printf("%d",ptr[k]);
   } 



    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: The corrected version which now just works fine can be viewed below:

```
int *max_sorted(int array[],int laenge, int max){
  int k;
  int l=0;
  int *ptr;
  int i=0;

  ptr= malloc((max+1)*sizeof(int)); /*allocates memory for new array*/
  if(ptr==NULL || max<0){
    return NULL;   /*error*/
  }
  for(k=0; k<max+1; k++){      /*sets all values of ptr array to 0*/
    ptr[k]=0; 
  }


  for(k=0;k<laenge;k++){               
    ptr[array[k]]++;      
   }


  for(k=0;k<max+1;k++){
    l=ptr[k];
    while(l>0){
      array[i]=k;
      i++;
      l--;
    }

  }


  free(ptr);
  return array;
}
```

Comment: In `max_sorted` the `l` variable is never initialized.

Comment: Oh God, I am so stupid... Thank you!

Comment: ...there may be more errors though.

Comment: according to your introduction & explaination of the variables. laenge is the variable of how large the array is? But you are using max to malloc the ptr that is guess is used to store sorted values in. in the code Example its just pure luck that both max and laenge is holding the same value (3)

Comment: Why do you have `max` **and** `laenge`. You array has just one length.

Comment: @MichaelWalz just to confuse us and himself ;)

Comment: and this line `ptr[array[k]]++;` looks rather fishy.

Comment: @MichaelWalz `ptr` points to an array that counts how many instances of each value there are in `array`. `max` is the same as the highest value in `array`. I don't understand the rest of the algorithm though.

Comment: @JeremyP P.S: The algorithm seems to be working fine if the numbers in the array do not repeat.

Comment: each error encountered in the function: `max_sorted()` should be displayed separately.  And the error from the call to `malloc()` should be output using `perror()` so the reason the OS thinks the call failed is also output..

Comment: the function: `max_sorted()` can return NULL, but the function: `main()` is not checking the returned value, so when `max_sorted()` returned NULL, the call to `printf()` in `main()` will cause a seg fault event to occur.

Comment: I edited the code and now everything just works fine. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code. indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is visible even with variable width fonts. 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: to set all values in the `malloc'd` array to 0, would be much better to have called `calloc()` rather than `malloc()`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding these lines: `if(ptr[k]!=0)
        {
            array[k-l]=k*ptr[k];`   if ptr[0] is > 0, which it can be, then this expression: `array[k-1]` is referencing memory outside the bounds of the array.  This is undefined behavior and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: @user3629249 Please see my updated version.

Answer (score 0):

the EDITED posted code is still not correct.

Here is a version of the code that

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired function
3. still depends on the contents of the array to avoid undefined behavior

and now the code

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // calloc(), free(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE



int *max_sorted(int array[], 
                size_t laenge, 
                size_t numElementsInArray);



int main( void )
{
    int array[] = { 2,1,3 };
    size_t laenge=3;

    size_t k;
    int*ptr;

    ptr=max_sorted( array, laenge, sizeof( array )/sizeof(int) );

    for( k=0; k<(sizeof( array )/sizeof(int)); k++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", ptr[k] );  //<-- note space in format string
    }

    return 0;         // <-- in modern C, when main returns 0, this line not needed
} // end function: main


int *max_sorted( int array[],      // array to be sorted
                 size_t laenge,    // largest value in array
                 size_t numElementsInArray ) 
{
    int *ptr = calloc( numElementsInArray+1, sizeof(int) ); /*allocates memory for new array*/
    if(!ptr)
    { // then calloc failed
        perror( "calloc for temporary array failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    for( size_t i=0; i<laenge; i++ )
    {
        ptr[ array[i] ]++;      // <-- this will have undefined behavior
                                //     when array[i] > 3
    }

    size_t index2 = 1;
    for( size_t index1=1; index1<(numElementsInArray+1); index1++ )
    {
        if( ptr[index1] )
        {
            array[index1-index2] = (int)index1 * ptr[index1];
        }

        else
        {
            index2++;
        }
    }

    free(ptr);
    return array;
} // end function: max_sorted
```

The output from the above code is:

```
1 2 3
```

Comment: note:  if the lines in `main()` were changed to:     `int array[] = { 2,1,310 };
    size_t laenge=310;` then the current answer will result in a seg fault event.  So the current logic is not correct.  so you will need to either clarify the second parameter to `max_sorted()` or modify the logic